# How to keep dropdown alue saved in localstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

can someone show me how to get the value saved in local storage so that once the page is reloaded the div stays in the selected dropdown value?

here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".payment-type").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code... alter as per your requirements**

On change, you need to save select value in localStorage. You also need to check if value is stored in localStorage, if yes, then get the value from localStorage and set it as a value.

```
var paymentTypeValue = localStorage.getItem('paymentTypeValueLocal') || null;
  console.log(paymentTypeValue)

  $(document).ready(function(){
    paymentTypeValue && $(".payment-type").val(paymentTypeValue);

    $(".payment-type").change(function(){
      paymentTypeValue = ($(this).val());
      console.log('Setting paymentTypeValue to = ', paymentTypeValue);
      localStorage.setItem('paymentTypeValueLocal', paymentTypeValue); 
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks it words for the dropdown but the divs now shows everything previously upload selection it used to change.